# Can tall built in Kresky back to back gas wall heaters be converted to electric

Tags: walls, heater

I have back to back gas wall heaters that share a wall. 68 tall x 18 wide x 3.5 deep. The manifold has cracked and I am hoping to switch it to electric. Is that even possible or do they make electric heaters to fit my space. My house was built in 1947 and is plaster walls. The name plate says Kresky on the vent

Comment: A photo might help

Comment: Are these natural gas fired heaters vented through a flue through the roof? If so, then you might be able to get a new pair of natural gas heaters that would fit in the space. A 60-year-old heater might be unrepairable. It also might not meet modern safety standards.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

### Sounds like a 2-sided *wall furnace*. They're awesome!

First, this sounds like a 2-sided "Wall Furnace" similar to the current-model [Williams Monterey Plus](https://www.williamscomfortprod.com/products/furnaces/monterey-plus-top-vent-detail-page/) 5009822, or  [Empire](http://empirezoneheat.com/products/vented-wall-furnaces/b-vent-gravity-wall-furnaces/) GWT50W.  Both of those mount in a wall between rooms. Ours is between the living room and the hall.

They have the amazing characteristic of **working during power outages!** As they do not require electricity at all.   They are widely used in the "sun belt" - though we're not supposed to tell people in the snow belt that they exist :)

Note that some models do require electricity. This buys you nothing, so those are best avoided.  Tell your contractor what you want.  In the snow belt these units are not popular *for some reason* and it's likely that most HVAC contractors will try to convince you into buying something else. The problem is they have zero familiarity with these units and don't feel confident installing them, or prefer the higher profits they'd make from selling you something much more expensive. In that case, keep calling around.

These furnaces (in a box) cost under $1000, and even if installation is that much again, it's still a fairly inexpensive replacement.

### Is electric viable in your home?

These 2-sided furnaces are 50,000 BTU - which means to replace them with "toaster style" resistance electric heat will require 50,000 BTU = **16,000 watts** of heat. This will require provisioning 20,000 watts of electric service or 83 amps in a 240V electrical panel.  A house of your era has a 60 amp or possibly 100 amp service, so it isn't going to happen.  In fact, adding 83 amps to a home with 200A service isn't likely, because it's already 200A for a reason.
So resistive electric would probably necessitate a service upgrade - to 200A if you're currently at 100A, or to 400A if you're currently at 200A.  If you have 200A service right now, you can do a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation to see if 83 more amps will fit, *but I wouldn't get my hopes up*.  Electric service upgrades cost between $2000 and $5000 all-in.

Typical electric resistance heaters are [baseboard units such as Cadet](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Heating-Venting-Cooling-Heaters-Baseboard-Heaters/Cadet/Electric/N-5yc1vZc4kuZbdZ1z0uks9), since it's easy to put them in every room or on every wall, so you can put the heat where you want it. Each room (or even each unit) can have a separate thermostat, so you're not heating a whole house when you don't need to.

Williams makes [electric wall furnaces](https://www.williamscomfortprod.com/products/furnaces/electric-forsaire-detail-page/) of the same shape as their gas furnace - but they are only 31,000 BTU (so you'd probably need two of them) - and they require 50A *EACH* x 2, so you'd need 100A of additional electric service.

### More efficient electric alternatives

Electric heat is only 100% efficient, which is terrible because 300-600% is also available in the form of **heat pumps**.  I gather with a double-sided wall furnace, your house does not have a ducted forced-air heating system.  The typical answer for homes like that is a "Mini-Split" heat pump, with an outdoor unit and then one or more indoor heads making the heat. These are extremely well-suited for temperate climates where wall furnaces are popular, but the newer and foreign models [also work in places like Chicago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI&list=PLv0jwu7G_DFVIot1ubOZdR-KC-LFdOVqi&index=2).  As you might guess from "300-600% efficient", these require far less electricity than resistive electric heaters, so are easier to make happen on houses with smaller electric services.

And by "easier" I mean there are [new options for squeezing things onto a house's electric service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVLLNjSLJTQ) that wouldn't fit before. These methods could not possibly work with 83 amps of resistive electric heat, but certainly can work for a 20-30 amp heat pump.   (e.g. pause a tanked water heater when the heat pump is running; the water heater is a storage appliance so this works great.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't "convert" a gas heater to electric*. But you can just replace the whole thing. I am not familiar with Kresky, but based on the size you should be able to put Cadet or similar heaters in its place. The catch is that Cadet (and similar) heaters are basically giant toasters. They cost relatively little and are very reliable and are easy to install. The biggest cost may be running electric power to them, as they generally need dedicated circuits.

However, while electric resistance heaters are 100% efficient at converting electricity to heat, that is generally not the most energy/cost efficient way of generating heat. Depending on natural gas appliance efficiency and relative pricing of natural gas and electricity, generally natural gas heating is a bit less expensive to run. But the most efficient by far is a *heat pump*. The up-front cost is significant, but the energy savings can be huge. To figure out what will be best overall, you need to consider:

- Initial equipment cost (least for electric resistance, natural gas typically in the middle, heat pump highest)
- Air conditioning - if you also need air conditioning, the heat pump does that too and it is the clear winner.
- Price of electricity (per kWh and any peak demand charges) vs. price of natural gas
- Installation costs - varies a lot depending on size of building, location of heater relative to outside walls, breaker panel capacity (both available Amps and available breaker spaces) and many other factors.

* Exception: If you had a large natural gas furnace/air handler, replaced the *usual* heating system with a large heat pump, using the same air handler and had absolutely no other gas appliances in use (e.g., water heater replaced with electric, stove replaced with electric) and you wanted to totally remove the natural gas service, it would be practical and reasonable to put an electric resistance heat (giant toaster) inside the air handler to use as backup/supplemental heat on really cold days when the heat pump is not sufficient. But that's not OP's situation. If I were in that situation and didn't have a *requirement* to remove the natural gas and the system was functional (different if it has a cracked heat exchanger, for example) then I'd leave the natural gas in place as in addition to functioning as a supplement to the heat pump, a natural gas furnace/air handler can easily run on a small generator during an electric utility power outage.